# Constructing improper integrals that can be solved by ${\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\text{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\text{d}s}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

One useful formula evaluate some improper integrals is the following;

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\text{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\text{d}s}$$

where $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ is the Laplace transform of the function $f(t)$.

---

I know an example of this which is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\text{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\}\text{d}s=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^2+1}\text{d}s=\tan^{-1}(s)|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

---

Now I need to have some other examples to use this formula, I tried to construct (using inverse Laplace) but failed to do so.

Can you recommend me some easy examples as the one above?

---

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about $f(t)=\sin(at)e^{-bt}$ for constants $a,\,b>0$?

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\delta(t-\tau)}{t}{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\{\delta(t-\tau)\} \ {d}s=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\tau s }ds=\frac1{\tau}$$

Comment: Can I ask why you need to have some other examples? Are you presenting these to someone, are they to help you build an intuition of when you can apply this technique, or are you just curious? Knowing this might help others answer your question.

Comment: @Quanto this does not seem true https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+diracdelta%28t-x%29%2Ft+dt+from+0+to+infty

Comment: @Max0815 - $\tau >0$ is implicitly assumed.

Comment: Okay, I found another one. Technically... lol. We have $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{-2}+x^2}$$ with its laplace transform being ```MeijerG[{{1/4}, {}}, {{0, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 3/
   4}, {}}, s^4/256]/(4 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2))``` but mathematica can solve this meijer g integral quickly to be $\frac{\pi}4$.

Answer (score 2):

If you read it backward, we can combine that identity with the [Frullani integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61841/695196) to get the formula: $$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha f(\alpha s) - \beta f(\beta s)\, \mathrm{d}s = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f\right\}\left( \frac{t}{\alpha}\right) - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f\right\}\left( \frac{t}{\beta}\right)}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f\right\}\Big\vert_{t=0}^{t=\infty} \ln\left\vert\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right\vert
$$
where  $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(s)\right\}(t)$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(s)\right\}(t)$ exist.

---

One example you where can use this is
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \arctan\left( \frac{1}{x\pm 1}\right) - \frac{1}{\xi}\arctan\left(\frac{\xi}{x \pm \xi}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x = \ln|\xi|
$$
where two sign choices are independent of each other. This integral looks rather complicated considering the fact that the integrand can be discontinuous and that splitting the integral results into two divergent integrals. However, if you know that
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\sin(t)}{t}e^{-t} \right\} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)e^{-t(s+1)}}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t= \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t(s+1 +x)}\sin(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\, \mathrm{d}x=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{s+1}\right)
$$ then an immediate application of the formula with $\alpha = \pm 1$ and $\beta = \pm\frac{1}{\xi}$ gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

Inn this posting I describe a class of functions for which the formula stated by the OP holds.

Suppose $\int^\infty_0\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt$ converges, that is, for   $F(t)=\int^t_0 \frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}F(t)$ exists

For $s>0$, the function
$$\Phi(s)=\int^\infty_0\frac{f(t)}{t}e^{-st}\,dt$$
is well defined (the integral converges for all $s>0$), and
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\Phi(s)=\int^\infty_0\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt$$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4705455/121671) for example).

If we assume that for each $s>0$, the integral $\Phi(s)$ converges itself in the sense of Lebesgue, then we have that $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\Phi(s)=0$, and that
$$\Phi'(s)=-\int^\infty_0f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=-Lf(s)$$
Hence
$$-\Phi(s)+\Phi(0+)=\int^s_0Lf(y)\,dy$$

Letting  $s\rightarrow\infty$ yields

$$\Phi(0+)=\int^\infty_0\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt=\int^\infty_0 Lf(t)\,dt$$

---

***Some examples:***

- $f(t)=e^{-cs}\sin t$  for $c>0$
- $f(t)=\frac{1-e^{-t^2}}{t}$